# Require only the latest record in the table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i require only the latest record of every `varname` in the table using mysql.
Assuming the table to be

```
    ref, varname, timestamp
1, alex, 2015-05-06 19:40:40
2, charles, 2015-05-05 19:40:40
3, allen, 2015-05-05 19:40:40
4, alex, 2015-05-12 19:40:40
5, allen, 2015-05-08 19:40:40
```

I tried below query but it throws error

```
select A.timestamp, A.ref, A.varname from event_table A, 
    | (select max(timestamp) as mxtime, ref, varname 
           from event_table group by ref) B 
    where A.timestamp=B.mxtime 
        and A.ref=B.ref group by A.timestamp, A.ref 
    order by ref;
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: `, | (` <--- what's the vertical line here?

Comment: Error is `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '| (select max(timestamp)as mxtime, ref, varname, description from event_table gr' at line 1`   i thought `|` would redirect as in unix.

Comment: But in unix pipes are not prepended with comma though :-D In unix there is no `SELECT`. Do you randomly choose the concepts you like and expect their arbitrary combination to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, you just want to select only those rows with the largest (latest) date value. You were on the right track -- you just made it more complicated than it really is.

```
select  A.timestamp, A.ref, A.varname
from    event_table A
where   A.timestamp=(
    select  Max( timestamp )
    from    event_table
    where   ref = A.ref )
order by ref;
```

Comment: Thanks Tomm. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

If your records are ordered by timstamp, you can use MAX like this:

```
select A.timestamp, A.ref, A.varname 
from event_table A
JOIN (select ref, max(timestamp) as mxtime
   from event_table group by ref
  ) B 
where A.timestamp=B.mxtime and A.ref=B.ref  
order by ref;
```

If your "last" record is not the "latest" record, you will need the window function.

Comment: I would use ON not WHERE there but I guess it works either way

Answer (score 1):

Such a common problem and so rarely do I see anyone suggest the self join rather than sub-queries.. I personally prefer to self join the table to pull the values that you need.. e.g.

```
SELECT A.timestamp, A.ref, A.varname
FROM event_table A

LEFT OUTER JOIN event_table B ON A.varname = B.varname
    AND A.timestamp > B.timestamp

WHERE B.ref IS NULL
```

If the timestamps are also in the same order as a unique indexed field then you can make the comparison on that field to further speed up the query. e.g. if each *newer* timestamp is always added *after* (with a greater var value) than an earlier timestamp then you would replace:

```
AND A.timestamp > B.timestamp
```

with

```
AND A.ref > B.ref
```